# php get the value of a constant

Tags: php, php-5.3, class-constants

I want to get the value of a constant "test" using "test1".

I have tried it but only getting "test1" value but not "test" value.

```
<?php

    class test
    {
        const test='fast';
        const test1=test;

        function testing()
        {

            echo test::test1;


        }
    }



<?php
include_once('class.test.php');

$d=new test;

echo $d->testing();

?>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `const test1 = self::test;` to define your constant.

Comment: Also, it is cleaner to use `echo self::test1`.

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to close this question if your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Below is just a working solution, but you have to consider about lot of things such as naming conventions:

```
<?php
    class test
    {
        const test='fast';
        const test1=test;

        function testing()
        {

            echo self::test1;
            echo self::test1;

        }
    }
?>
<?php
include_once('class.test.php');    
$d=new test;    
echo $d->testing();

?>
```